# Checkbox to be selected according to database value

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help !, I am working on a project where I want to select all those check boxes, which has value fetched from database. Let suppose I have a table which has 4 fields as id, news_title, news_desc and flag. flag field has value like 0 for not checked and 1 for checked. now when I query that table I want only those check boxes which has flag value 1 should be checked and other are not not checked.. How can I do this.. Please Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know how to get the result from mysql you would put the following into your while results loop.

```
if ($row['flag'] == 1){
   echo '<input name="checkbox_name" id="checkbox_id" type="checkbox" checked="yes">';
}else{
    echo '<input name="checkbox_name" id="checkbox_id" type="checkbox">';
}
```

obviously this is just for illustration - there are better ways to do this (like storing `$checked = ""` or $checked = `'checked="yes"'` and the echoing it in-line).

in the HTML it can be `checked="yes"` or `checked`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$row` contains your result row, you could use something like:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="name"' . ($row['flag']==1?'selected="selected"':null) . '/>';
```